# Spannable text that holding custom view

Tags: android, html, android-view, android-spannable

Is that possible to add a custom view into a spannable text?

In `android.text.style` package I can see many types of spannable objects, but I wonder if I can add a custom view.

Sort of `spanable.setSpan(CustomView, .. , .. ,..)`

Note that: CustomView maybe any sort of view i.e: `WebView`

Comment: The question should be if it is advisable to add a view as reference to a `Spannable`. Since a view contains a context and the spannable string is not bound to any lifecycle, you should not put the reference there.

Comment: @tynn you're right regarding to view's context/lifecycle?...BUT what about saving references in WeakHashMap and destroy them once I left the `SpannableText` MainView.? SO my question still exist... is that possible to inject custom-view into the spanabble text?

Comment: Do you simply want the custom view to appear within the text as an image? This would be as it would appear in a _ViewGroup_ but fitting within the text bounds? Would you want the custom view to be operational beyond its display, i.e., be clickable, accept focus, be editable, etc.

Comment: @Cheticamp I think the custom view cannot come with beyond display attributes.. while I can handle clicks like I did with `<a href` BUT for now I'm trying to just displaying them as an image at least.

Comment: An _ImageSpan_ will display an image within the text but you will need a bitmap or some kind of drawable from your custom view. If an _ImageSpan_ works, does your question reduce to how to get a bitmap or something that can be used for the _ImageSpan_ from the custom view? (I don't think that wonsuc's answer is too far afield. I question the statement about _ViewGroups_ but, as far as I can tell, @wonsuc's answer is not about animations.)

Comment: @Cheticamp Please feel free to post an answer : )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So looks like it will be challenging to use Spannable way to handle such case.

Therefore I created a [new library](https://github.com/pushbots/HtmlParser) to handle tags so I can use them wherever I want.

And here is an example

```
HtmlParser.Builder(StringSource(source)).setCallback(object : HtmlParser.ParserCallbacks {
override fun onParseFinished(list: List<Element>) {
list.forEach {
        Log.d(TAG, "onParseFinished: ${ElementType.values()[it.type]} ||| ${it.toString()}")
    if (it is ImageElement) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onImageFound: $it ||| ${it.ImageUrl}")
    } else if (it is IFrameElement) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onIFrameFound: $it ||| ${it.url}")
    } else if (it is BlockQuoteElement) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBlockQuoteFound: ${it.data} ${it.text}")
    } else if (it is FigureElement) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onFigure: ${it.caption}  ${it.url}")
    }
 } 
 } override fun onParseError(exception: Exception) {}})
   .build()
```

Now I can handle elements in whatever I want i.e: `RecycleView`

Answer (score 1):

In Android, only `ViewGroup` class can contain another view, therefore it's much proper to say,

**Is that possible to add a spannable text into a custom view?**

Then the answer is **Yes**, if your custom view extends `ViewGroup` class.

However, if you want to draw specific graphics or animations with spannable, you would need to draw on the `Canvas` directly from your custom view.

For examples, if you check `DynamicDrawableSpan` class in `android.text.style` package.

```
@Override
public void draw(@NonNull Canvas canvas, CharSequence text,
        @IntRange(from = 0) int start, @IntRange(from = 0) int end, float x,
        int top, int y, int bottom, @NonNull Paint paint) {
    Drawable b = getCachedDrawable();
    canvas.save();

    int transY = bottom - b.getBounds().bottom;
    if (mVerticalAlignment == ALIGN_BASELINE) {
        transY -= paint.getFontMetricsInt().descent;
    } else if (mVerticalAlignment == ALIGN_CENTER) {
        transY = (bottom - top) / 2 - b.getBounds().height() / 2;
    }

    canvas.translate(x, transY);
    b.draw(canvas);
    canvas.restore();
}
```

It has `draw` method which draw the `Drawable` on the `Canvas` directly, this code will be good start if you want to create custom spannable class which displays various things more than existing SDK classes.